# How to check if signed in Firebase user has a Password

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app uses Firebase authentication with two providers(email/password and Google SignIn) but I require all my users to have a password so they can use any of these providers to sign in, now my problem is I want that each user that sign in using a provider different from email/password should be prompted to create a password immediately but I cannot find any method in the SDK to check if a user has a password.

I tried using the method below to check that but from my observation, this checks only for the provider the user used to Sign Up.

```
for(UserInfo info : currentUser.getProviderData()) {
    if(!info.getProviderId().equals("password")) {
        ShowUpdateUserPasswordDialog("CREATE",currentUser);
    } else {
        MoveToMainActivity();
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I require all my users to have a password so they can use any of these providers to sign in

Firebase authentication with email and password is a totally different authentication mechanism than the authentication with the Google provider.

> now my problem is I want that each user that sign in using a provider different from email/password should be prompted to create a password immediately

If the user has chosen to sign-in with Google, why would you force him to enter a password? That's the whole idea, not to use a password anymore. Besides that, you let the user choose even from the beginning what kind of authentication to use. It's some kind of a bad user experience to force the user to choose one, or the other, or both.

However, if you still want to force the user the choose a password, you first need to sign-out the user from Google and Firebase so it can be signed in again with email and password. You can do that silently, but how about the situation in which the user wants to choose a password for the Gmail account that is already in use? In that situation you'll get an error, saying the account with that particular email already exists.

> but I cannot find any method in the SDK to check if a user has a password

You didn't find something like that because something like that doesn't exist.

IMHO, some kind of operation might be considered bad practices and I cannot see any reason for doing that. You should let the user choose the type of authentication according to their own will.

Comment: thanks for that info, now I think I will instead move that part to my user profile page where the user can then choose if  he/she should add a password or not

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome, Emmanuel!